Problem with calculating sum of infinite series (maybe telescopic)
How can i calculate this:
$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n+4}{(n+5)!}$
I already checked that it converges.
I though about telescopic series but I'm unable to get there.

$n+4=(n+5)-1$. Use exponential series.

Got it. thank you so much!

So, your intuition of a telescopic series was fine! $\frac{n+4}{(n+5)!}=x_n-x_{n+1}$, for $x_n:=\frac1{(n+4)!}$.

\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n+4}{(n+5)!}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n+4)!}-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n+5)!}\\
=\frac{1}{4!}=\frac{1}{24}
\end{align}
